# Trouble in connect with Connect Live --- SkyDrive Synchronizer with Azure Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, onedrive, live-sdk

I want to synchronize files between Skydrive and Azure blob storage.

I will run one background process on worker role which will do all this sync.

1. User Come to our website
2. Attach their sky drive account
3. Sign in on sky drive using oAuth on our website and grant access to
   our site and our app get token
4. Now this token will pass to background process which runs all time to check files on sky drive and sync on azure blob storage.

**However, What is a save way to get thsi user authenticated in background service. because even after user left our website our background service will keep sync all attached Sky drive account. but I have problem here with oAuth how will get authentication in background where no user interaction can be done.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Azure Mobile Service is something that you should check out.
e.g. the following link talks how to integrate with azure blob storage.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190

Then there is live SDK Skydrive API which is restful, so seems like you can use Azure Mobile Service to do the job you requestsed.  Also the service allows you run the scheduled jobs.